# Control an image Behind Text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using Word 14. I created macros that work with images that are In-Line with Text, such as

```
Selection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
```

and also to center an image

```
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

How do I manipulate an image that is positioned behind text?
Is this possible? I can't select this image while recording a macro.

I have a small square image measuring 1.2 cm x 1.2 cm (approx. 1/2 inch square) positioned Behind Text (or In Front of Text). Its horizontal position is always 0 cm to the right of the margin, and its vertical position has an absolute position somewhere below the margin, for example 4.2 cm.

I'd like to copy this image and then paste it at the same vertical position (4.2 cm below the margin) but further across the page at a horizontal position of (3.7 cm to the right of the margin).

Answer (score 0):

For shapes that are configured to wrap behind text, the `WrapFormat.Type` property will return `wdWrapBehind`.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim objDoc As Document
    Dim objShp As shape, dupShape As shape
    Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
    For Each objShp In objDoc.Shapes
        ' Get the shape object (Behind Text)
        If objShp.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind Then
            objShp.Select
            Selection.Copy
            Selection.Range.Paste
            Set dupShape = Selection.ShapeRange(1)
            dupShape.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
            ' set shape object location
            dupShape.Top = objShp.Top
            dupShape.Left = InchesToPoints(1.46) ' 3.7cm = 1.46inch
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
End Sub
```

Please ref to Microsoft document about the syntax of WrapFormat.Type.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wrapformat.type?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. I forgot to mention that I only want to do one image at a time, likely always the last image as I write the document page by page. Learning from your code (Document, Shapes, Selection, Range, etc) I finally ended up with this which appears to do what I need. Not understanding it too much I'm hoping it won't cause problems with my document.

```
Dim objDoc As Document
Dim dupShape As Shape
Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
n = objDoc.Shapes.Count     ' Last obj added to document
m = n + 1                   ' New obj being added here
' Get position of last obj added
it = objDoc.Shapes(n).Top
il = objDoc.Shapes(n).Left
'Copy/Paste
objDoc.Shapes(n).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.Range.Paste
' set new obj position
objDoc.Shapes(m).Top = it
objDoc.Shapes(m).Left = il + 104.7    ' 104.7 =  3.7cm (1.46")
```